# Ember json search with multiple TextFields

Tags: ember.js

Ember noob here. I'm basically trying to have multiple input fields for multiple parameters. As the user types into the fields, this sends off a request to a PHP script which returns the relevant JSON and displays it.

- Ember 1.6.1 (latest version is a pain to learn as all of the docs are
  out of date)
- Handlebars 1.3.0
- jQuery 1.11.1

Here's the code so far (not working for multiple).

index.html

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="search">
    {{view App.SearchTextField elementId="bedrooms" valueBinding=bedrooms upKeyAction="searchProperties" placeholder="Bedrooms"}}
    {{view App.SearchTextField elementId="suburb" valueBinding=suburb upKeyAction="searchProperties" placeholder="Sydney"}}

    {{outlet}}
  </script>      

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="search/results">
    {{#each}}
      <h1>{{bedrooms}} - {{street}} {{suburb}}</h1>
    {{/each}}
  </script>
```

apps.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('search', {path: '/'}, function(){
    this.route('results', {path: '/search/:suburb/:bedrooms'});
  });
});

App.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    searchProperties: function(suburb, bedrooms) {
        console.log(suburb);
      this.transitionTo('search.results', suburb, bedrooms);
    }
  }
});

App.SearchResultsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
      return Ember.$.getJSON('../test/data.php?suburb='+params.suburb+'&bedrooms='+params.bedrooms);
  }
});

App.SearchTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  keyUp: function (e) {
      if (e.target.id == 'bedrooms') {
          var bedrooms = e.target.value;
      } else if (e.target.id == 'suburb') {
          var suburb = e.target.value;
      }
      console.log(suburb + bedrooms);
      this.sendAction('action', suburb, bedrooms);
  }
});
```

After some playing around I got it to work using this (looking more jQuery than Ember, but hey it works)

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('search', {path: '/'}, function(){
    this.route('results', {path: '/search/:suburb/:bedrooms'});
  });
});

App.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    searchProperties: function(data) {
      this.transitionTo('search.results', data.suburb, data.bedrooms);
    }
  }
});

App.SearchResultsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
      return Ember.$.getJSON('../test/data.php?suburb='+params.suburb+'&bedrooms='+params.bedrooms);
  }
});

App.SearchTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  keyUp: function (e) {
      var data = {suburb:$('#suburb').val(), bedrooms:$('#bedrooms').val()};
      this.sendAction('upKeyAction', data);
  }
});
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are kind of over complicating things IMO,

I'd prefer to observe for the value changes in the controller and act accordingly. Result in much reduced code, and in fact you are actually exploiting the features, the framework provides.

Sample implementation, may need to modify to fulfill your needs

```
App.SearchController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  suburb : null,
  bedrooms : null,

  doSearch : function(){
    var model = [{street: this.get('suburb'), bedrooms: this.get('bedrooms')}];
    //var model = Ember.$.getJSON('../test/data.php?suburb='+this.get('suburb')+'&bedrooms='+this.get('bedrooms'));
    this.transitionToRoute('search.results', model);
  }.observes('suburb', 'bedrooms')
});

App.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
});

App.SearchResultsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
});

App.SearchTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({});
```

[FIDDLE](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ronopamawe/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: Awesome! Thankyou so much! I noticed when I change var model to pull the json data, the new URL is full of /undefined/undefined. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I moved the getJSON request back into the SearchResultsRoute. Only issue now is working out how to urlencode the parameters in the URL. Particularly for suburb if it consists of two words

Comment: won't `+encodeURIComponent(this.get('suburbs')) +&` work for you?